# GitHub API doesn't return any issues labelled "good first issue"

Tags: github-api

I am writing an app for finding GitHub issues and I've found that calling the API to find issues labelled "good first issue" does not bring back any results.

Below are 2 API calls for languages C# and JavaScript searching for this issue. Neither yield any results.

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=label:good%20first%20issue+language:csharp+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=label:good%20first%20issue+language:javascript+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1

This isn't correct as there is a C# issue labelled "good first issue" [here](https://github.com/NRKirby/FindGitHubIssues/issues/2).

My guess is there are many thousands of issues with this label. Does anyone know why I can't return any via the API?

**More info**

Calling the API for C# issues labelled "good-first-issue" brings back 11 results:

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=label:good-first-issue+language:csharp+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1

Comment: Add "" marks around the string for your label? https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=label:%22good%20first%20issue%22+language:javascript+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1

Comment: Searching for `label:good first issue` without quotes looks for issues that are labeled "good" and contain the words "first" and "issue".

Comment: Thanks @JamesGreenhalgh! If you post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Done as community wiki as half the answer isn't mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JJJ points out in the comments:

> Searching for `label:good first issue` without quotes looks for issues that are labeled `"good"` and contain the words `"first"` and `"issue"`.

The appropriate search would group these together:

```
label:"good first issue"
```

Translating to the two URLs you provided in your question:

C#:

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=label:%22good%20first%20issue%22+language:csharp+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1

Javascript:

https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=label:%22good%20first%20issue%22+language:javascript+state:open&sort=created&order=desc&per_page=100&page=1